# Django escape date formatting

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a TIME field in mysql that I want to display exactly as it is in my django template.

However, when I use the value, django interprets it as a date object.

```
{{ start_time }}

12:01 a.m. // should be 00:01:02
```

How do I get django to interpret this value correctly as `00:01:02`?

Comment: do you want this format across the site ? or to this specific instance ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems a bit hackish, but you need to use the time filter and format it manually:

```
{{ qc_note.start_time|time:"H:i:s" }}
```